# Deleting records based on 1 cell not matching criteria

Tags: ms-access, vba

So basically I have a list of records in the following format.

```
StockCode      BomReference

 2112003         5113016
 2112003         5109200
 2112113         5112113
 2112113         5112129
 2112113         5112127
 2112113         5113014
 2112113         5113039
 2112113         5113014TC
 2112120         5112120
```

I would like to query this information so that, if the BomReference does not begin "511" then it will not return the StockCode associated with the BomReference.

From the records above, the result from the query would be;

```
StockCode      BomReference

 2112113         5112113
 2112113         5112129
 2112113         5112127
 2112113         5113014
 2112113         5113039
 2112113         5113014TC
 2112120         5112120
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want:
All of the records EXCEPT any StockCode that has one or more BomReference that doesn't start with '511'.

StockCodes that DO have one or more BomReference unlike '511*':

```
SELECT DISTINCT StockCode FROM YourTable WHERE BomReference not like '511*'
```

Therefore, your whole query should be

```
SELECT StockCode, BomReference 
FROM YourTable 
WHERE StockCode NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT StockCode 
                        FROM YourTable 
                        WHERE BomReference NOT LIKE '511*')
```